# Linux server for Odroid HC2

Tags: debian, ubuntu, arm

Years ago I bought the [OdroidHC2](https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-hc2-home-cloud-two/) to build a small home server running [NextcloudPi](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloudpi). The hardware was since discontinued. After having problems with this installation multiple times I now want to switch to running multiple dockerized services.

Therefore, I want to install an **up-to-date** linux server distribution. I gathered, that I need a `32bit`, `arm` image for this. These are the images I tried so far:

- https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm (only 64bit version seems available so this obviously does not work)
- https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi (32bit version, still does not work)
- https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-xu4/os_images/linux/ubuntu_5.4/ubuntu_5.4 (from odroid directly, because the HC2-page said all XU4 images are compatible, also doesn't work)

I also tried different versions of debian (and getting confused by which version I need), to no avail. With non of these images the HC2 starts, only a red light stays on. I tried the last version of NextcloudPi that is made for the HC2 to verify that the hardware still works: https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloudpi/releases/tag/v1.48.2. This image runs without a problem.

All images where burned to an sd-card via: `sudo dd bs=4M if=<image>.img of=/dev/sda status=progress oflag=sync`.

To sum up my question: Where can I find an image that runs on my hardware, why do the images I tried don't work?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of reasons why your Odroid might not be running, it's a bit difficult to diagnose without more information. The fact that the blue heartbeat LED is not blinking does suggest that linux wasn't able to boot.

What happens when you try to ssh into your HC2? Is the device visible on your network router after it boots? You could use a USB-UART cable to try to see what is going wrong during boot.

If you're just looking for a distribution to run on the HC2, the [Armbian OS](https://www.armbian.com/odroid-xu4/) should work. You could also use something like [OpenMediaVault](https://www.openmediavault.org/) to run docker and other services.